# Reading Lines from File and Storing it in List

Tags: python, arrays, list, file

I am reading lines from a text file and I want each line in the list to be part of a different element in the array.

```
with open("diceRoll.txt","r") as x_file:
    contents = x_file.readlines()

oneScore = contents[count-1]
oneScore = oneScore.split(" ")
print(oneScore)
n = oneScore[0] + " " + oneScore[
```

When I run the program once, I get this response:

```
['i', '68']
```

When I run the program twice, I get this response:

```
['i', '68j', '22']
```

How can I change my code so that when I run my program twice, I would receive `68, j,`, instead of `'68j'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
lines_list=[line.split(“ “) for line in open(“diceRoll.txt”,”r”)]
last_line=lines_list[-1]
```

should get you the lines of the file as list of lists and give you the last line of the file.